# ASP.NET MVC 4 Dev Preview Razor in Sections Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Well, I think the ASP.NET MVC team released a pretty significant bug in the developer preview for asp.net mvc 4, or I'm doing something stupid...  Here's the issue and steps to reproduce.

1. Create a new MVC 4 mobile application
2. create a new section in the layout (ex. @RenderSection("head",false))
3. in the controller action just throw a Message into the ViewBag
4. then in a view that uses the main layout, add the following code below.

```
@section head {
    $(function() { 
        var newVariableName = "@(ViewBag.Message)";
    });
}
```

You'll notice that the razor parser actually thinks that the section has been completed for the jquery on dom loaded ending brace instead of the section's ending brace.  I tried the exact same code in an asp.net MVC 3 application and it worked with no issues.

Has anyone else come across this bug in the ASP.NET MVC 4 Developer Preview?

Comment: yes, me! you have got incompleted javascript code as output, right?

Comment: Yea, it basically considers it terminated.  How did this developer preview get released with a bug this ridiculous? Also, how has nobody posted something about it!

Comment: I actually attempted to post this but I always thought that the problem is on my code (my javascript code was a little complicated). I mean it is developer preview, you cannot expect much. Also, you do not have a go-live licence. you know that, right? If dev. preview blows up your machine, it is on you, not on MSFT.

Comment: David's got the right solution for now. We're aware of the issue and have fixed it. Remember, Dev Preview isn't for production use for a reason!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick hack to solving this issue is to use < text > blocks < /text > around the java script.  Here's what it might look like until the ASP.NET MVC team resolves this bug.

```
@{
<text>
    $(function()
    {
        var newVariableName = "@(ViewBag.Message)";
    });
</text>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, try this in your cshtml file...

```
@section head {
@{
    function JSMeth1()
    {
        // doing your stuff, razor parser wont suck
    }
}}
```